# How to check in java if user is clicking save button unnecessarily and there is nothing to save?

Tags: java, validation, equals

In my piece of code there is one input box so data will be fetched in that box on drop down selection. And if user do not want to insert/update/delete that data and click on save button unnecessarily then i have to show an error message that: "There is nothing to save..You pressed the save button unnecessary."

Currently , i am checking if the data in input box is equals to the  database value then show that error but its not working.

```
if (inputVal1.equals(dbVal1.getValue()) && inputVal2.equals(dbVal2.getValue())) {
    addPageError(T_NOTHING_TO_SAVE);
}
```

Please suggest how to handle this validation in java.

Comment: What you tried so far. Please post your attempt here.

Comment: Is variable `inputVal1` a string? [Edit] your question and post the code that assigns a value to variable `inputVal1`. What is the type of variable `dbVal1`? Also post the code that assigns a value to that variable (and don't just post one line that starts with `dbVal1 = ...`) In order to help you debug your code, I need to see more than two lines of it. Obviously your `if` condition is not returning **true**. In order to understand why, I need to see what values you are assigning to the variables in the `if` condition.

Comment: both the values are of String type but while comparing both the values..getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in a separate variable and simply compare it to the current values in the input box. If you do this, you could even detect if the values were changed, but then changed back to the original value. Apart from this you could also even deactivate the button and compare in an edit-event of the input box if the content has really changed and enable the button accordingly.